# How to use the update method for a generic linq to entities repository

Tags: c#

I have implemented the following code:

**Generic Repository:**

```cs
public abstract class BaseRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
        public void Update(T entity)
        {
            using (Context context = new Context())
            {
                context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
}
```

**specific repository:**

```
public class RoleRepository : BaseRepository<Role>
{

}
```

**Business Layer:**

```
public class RoleBL
{
    static RoleRepository rolRepository = new RoleRepository();


    public static Role Edit(int RoleId)
    {
        return rolRepository.Single(r => r.RoleId == RoleId);
    }
    public static void Update(Role roleData)
    {
        rolRepository.Update(roleData);
    }
}
```

**UI Layer:**

```
private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Role role = new Role()
    {
        RoleId = this.roleId,
        Name = txtName.Text,
        Description = txtDescription.Text
    };
    RoleBL.Update(role);
}
```

When I click the Refresh button I have the following errors:

**A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll**

**Additional information: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.**